# Is there any problem in creating a folder in the system root and saving all my personal files there?

Tags: directory, home-directory

I'm thinking of make `/myFiles` my new home directory.

I am thinking of this possibility because I have had problems with exact path of files on different computers. I use more than one computer every day, and have some programs that need to find files to work properly. However, because of the difference between `/home/user1/myFiles/thisFile.doc` and `/home/user2/myFiles/thisFile.doc` the programs do not work properly.

(I know I can use symbolic links for this kind of problem, but I would not want to use this artifice - they are too many files, I would have to do this for each one and it would not become viable in my workflow)

Is there any problem or conflict that might be occasioned by doing so or theoretically would everything be okay?

I want to make `/myFiles` my home directory and not just create a `/myFiles` folder at the root of the system as I think it will make my workflow easier. although it is something unusual, would theoretically have some problem in doing so?

(and, if I want to go back to my current `/home/username/myFiles` state, having `/home/username/` as my home directory, is there any problem?) I mean, is this action reversible if I do not like it for some reason?

Comment: How would you use it? Do you want to make `/myFiles` your default home directory or is that just a place where you want to keep your personal files?

Comment: I want to make `/myFiles` my new home directory. So when I need to move to a new computer, for example, I can just copy my personal files directory to the root of the system and change the $HOME of this computer to `/myFiles` and everything will work normally (links, scripts, settings in programs , etc..). That's the intention, but I do not know if it's that simple

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify that. Also, please explain why you would want that. Why change the location of your home directory instead of simply keeping your files somewhere that isn't your home directory?

Comment: Don't think there's a problem with it, but I don't see the benefit of it. Why not `/home/myfiles` or provide the same username, or use symlinks to fix your issues. Btw if your scripts depend on absolute paths from your home folder, there's something wrong somewhere else. You could simply use `$HOME` or `~` as path.